# Custom Code Snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In visual studio in c# you can do this

`for` then you press `tab` + `tab` and it makes this

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    //Code here
}
```

Could i make a short cut like that?

Comment: Just google for code snippets

Comment: Read this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is called a snippet.
Snippets are suggested by intellisense.

You can customize your own.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGmXlUFMTpk) is a video for introduction.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165393(v=vs.100).aspx) is the MSDN- Documentation for doing so.

Shortcuts are a little different. These are certain combinations of keys that are bound to a function of Visual Studio (like copy and paste). But you can also customize them to a certain degree.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301747(v=vs.71).aspx) you can find ho to do it.

Hope this helps